# PHP form - Processing Textfield isn't working

Tags: php, html

I am currently trying to make a form validation which checks wether some inputs / a textfield are empty or not. I want the text in a textfield to be saved and entered in the next php file in the textfield again. It works with all inputs but not with the textfield. The site loads but the textfield is just empty.

THank you in anticipation!

HTML PART:

```
<form id="formularheader" name="form" method="post" action="php/contact.php">
                        <fieldset id="personenInfo">


                            <p><label for="message" >Nachricht *</label></p>
                            <p><textarea name="nachricht" id="message" cols="40" rows="10" required=""></textarea></p>

                            <div class="terms">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="terms">
                            </div>

                            <p style="font-size: 80%; color: #292929; font-style: italic;">* notwendige Angaben</p>
                        </fieldset>

                        <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Abschicken">
                    </form>
```

PHP PART:

```
<?php 

$message = $_POST['message'];

?>

<form id="formularheader" name="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
                        <fieldset id="personenInfo">

                            <p><label for="message">Nachricht *</label></p>
                            <p><textarea name="nachricht" id="message" value="<? echo $message; ?>" cols="50" rows="10" required=""></textarea></p>

                            <div class="terms">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="terms">
                            </div>

                            <p style="font-size: 80%; color: #292929; font-style: italic;">* notwendige Angaben</p>
                        </fieldset>

                        <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Abschicken">
                    </form>
```

Comment: I found out that a TEXTAREA, excuse me for the wrong title, does not know "value". This was the second mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should be `$_POST["nachricht"]`   (name attribute is taken in account when in a POST)

Comment: thanks, I changed it, but for some reason the result is still the same.

Comment: ... may be a side-effect... then make the name attribute be message: `name="message"` and use `$_POST["message"]` again

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the field name as opposed to the ID e.g. $_POST['NAME'] whereas you have  $_POST['id']

Answer (score 0):

More than one level of validation can be used:

1. use the HTML5 tool : add required to each input to deny the user from sending empty input
2. use if(isset())

Comment: I have deleted those parts to make the code easier to read, but thanks!